# How to open problematic data dump and convert it to mysql (or some other practical format)?

Tags: mysql, data-dump

I'm trying to work with pretty interesting data set. Unfortunately, I have problems with opening it and converting it into any useful format. It's collection of archived txt files. When i decompress them and try to open txt file i get 'it's binary file, saving it may result in corrupt file' and it's unreadable - there are just 'weird characters', nothing i could manually read. Tried to use grep but it's also complaining that it's binary. I tried to import it into mysql database but when i tried to execute  `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘/path/to/file.txt’ INTO TABLE tablename` I got `ERROR 1064 (42000)`. I don't know what to do to open it.

Comment: does the command 'file' say anything sensible about it, run 'file yourstrangefile'

Comment: 'file' says 'gzip compressed data' - very odd, i just tried to open it with archiver too and it can't open it, because, uhm, it's not archive ;))

Comment: so if file says "gzip compressed data", what does "gunzip yourfile" say?

Comment: rename it to have a .gz suffix, and run gunzip on the file

Comment: renamind it to .gz and running gunzip worked! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a wild guess here and say they're not really text files :-)

And until you figure what they are, trying to import them via different methods is not going to be the most productive course of action.

Can you post (a hex code of) headers for those files? If they have magic sequence in front, it should help with figuring out what they are.

Comment: I take it you're on Linux since you can run 'file yourfile'? `hexdump -x -n 80 yourfile`